# How to load a ComboBox in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, combobox, uwp

I have the following `ComboBox` in XAML:

```
<ComboBox Header="Cities" Width="245" SelectedItem="{Binding Cities, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

And I need to populate it with a List in a `ViewModel`:

```
public List<City> Cities = new List<City>();
```

The list is populated by a query that is run in the API:

```
public async void CargarCiudades()
{
   var List = await App.Repository.City.GetAsync();
   foreach (var i in List)
   {
        this.Cities.Add(i);
   }
}
```

I need to load the ComboBox with the contents of the Cities list. How can I do it?

Comment: You can search here for the answer [ComboBox UWP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.combobox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **x:Bind** for better performance instead of **Binding** you dont need two way binding for filling data from backend and instead of binding to SelectedItem just use **ItemsSource** also make sure to use **ObservableCollection** instead of **List** this helps in updating UI automatically when an item is added or removed from your backend list.

```
<ComboBox Header="Cities" Width="245" ItemsSource="{x:Bind vm.Cities}"/>
```

in above code I am assuming **vm** is a property of type ( your viewmodel ) in the backend code of ur page ( yourPage.xaml.cs)

**ViewModel**

```
public ObservableCollection<City> Cities = new ObservableCollection<City>();

public async void CargarCiudades()
{
   var list = await App.Repository.City.GetAsync();
   foreach (var i in list)
   {
        this.Cities.Add(i);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The ComboBox does not know that new items have been added after it's bound to the List<City>.

If you change the Cities collection to ObservableCollection<City> instead it will work as you expectd.